# Angular event not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have an angular function that allows to drop a text file into a textarea and the contents are placed into the textbox.  The issue is this does not work in Firefox.  Any ideas?

[PLunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D8hu32H0tPYnx64ZjW57?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "";
})
.directive('plkrFileDropZone', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {content:'='},
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.content = "drop a .txt file here";

                var processDragOverOrEnter;

                processDragOverOrEnter = function (event) {
                    if (event !== null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
                    return false;
                };

                element.bind('dragover', processDragOverOrEnter);
                element.bind('dragenter', processDragOverOrEnter);
                element.bind('drop', handleDropEvent);

        function insertText(loadedFile) {

                scope.content = loadedFile.target.result;
          scope.$apply();
        }

                function handleDropEvent(event) {

                    if (event !== null) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = insertText;
                    reader.readAsText(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);

                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: should be using `ng-model` on the textarea, not trying to set text with `{{}}`

Comment: @charlietfl Changing that made no difference.  Works still in Chrome but not in FireFox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier solution remove the line

```
event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
```

Comment: Phenomenal! Thats was it! Thank you!

Comment: FYI, if you do decide to set the 'effectAllowed' for firefox you must define it for DragStart + DragEnter + DragOver event handlers for it to work.